# Is there a computationally cleaner way of working with inverse image functor $f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y$ in the category of schemes?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

Suppose $f:X\rightarrow Y$ is a morphism of schemes; is there a computationally cleaner way of working with $f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y$ than just using the raw definition? Anytime I need to use the inverse image functor I end up in a notational quagmire because I'm dealing with the sheafification of a presheaf defined in terms of a colimit, so I've got two colimits to work, over different indexing sets, and it's just a mess.

In particular, there are certain cases where, with some work with the raw definition, you can show you don't completely need it. For example, if $Z\subset X$ is a Zariski closed subset, then we get a sheaf of ideals $I_Z$ of $X$ determined by $Z$, and which induces a new sheaf of rings on $X$, denoted $\mathcal O_X/I_Z$, which for affine opens satisfies $\mathcal O_X/I_Z(U)\cong \mathcal O_X(U)/I_Z(U)$. The sheaf $\mathcal O_Z=\iota_{Z}^{-1}\mathcal O_X/I_Z$ on $Z$ is the one which gives $Z$ its induced reduced subscheme structure, and is a pain to work with directly. But, for every open affine of $U$ it satisfies $\mathcal{O}_Z(U\cap Z)\cong \mathcal O_X(U)/I_Z(U)$, so we never need to really work with the inverse image sheaf directly.

I doubt something as clean would hold in generality, but is there any argument I can make in specific cases that allows me to avoid working with the definition directly? In particular, I'd be very interested in the case of the definition of the pull back of a sheaf $G$ of $\mathcal{O}_Y$ modules:
$$f^*G=f^{-1}G\otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y}\mathcal O_X$$
which feels incredibly unwieldy to work with from the raw definitions.

I'd also be interested in the specific sub case of the sheaf of differentials on $X$ over $Y$, which is defined by:
$$\Omega_{X/Y}=\iota^*(I_{X/U}/I_{X/U}^2)$$
where $\iota:X\rightarrow U$ is the closed embedding in the diagram:
$$\Delta_{X/Y}:X\hookrightarrow U\hookrightarrow X\times_YX$$
and $I_{X/U}$ is the sheaf of ideals determined by the image of $\iota$.

Any advice or references would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: If $Z \subseteq X$ is a closed subscheme, locally on an affine open set $U:=Spec(A) \subseteq X$ it follows the ideal sheaf $I(Z)$ of $Z$ is satisfies $I(Z)(V) \cong \tilde{I}(V)$ for an ideal $I \subseteq A$. You work with the ideal sheaf $I(Z)$ using an open affine cover hence you work with an ideal $I$ in a commutative ring $A$. You seldom use the topological inverse image $f^{-1}(I(Z))$ for a morphism $f: Y \rightarrow X$, in calculations. Sometimes in the EGA book series you will find they use the topological inverse image when making general constructions,

Comment: ..but they seldom do any explicit calculations using $f^{-1}(I(Z))$.

Comment: @hm2020 Yes, that is part of the argument that goes into the reduced induced subscheme case. You have something similar again in the sheaf of differentials, in the sense that you have an ideal sheaf on $U$, but pulling it back it is a pain that has two separate sheafifications, and so like three different colimits to work with

Comment: Im unsure what litterature you are reading, but the EGA book series is a good reference for studying "the language of schemes". This series is self contained and can be read with some knowledge in commutative algebra. I didn't even know french when I read it and I had no problems.  Use this book-series in addition to a more elementary book, such as the classical Hartshorne book.

Comment: "I doubt something as clean would hold in generality, but is there any argument I can make in specific cases that allows me to avoid working with the definition directly? In particular, I'd be very interested in the case of the definition of the pull back of a sheaf $G$ of $\mathcal{O}_Y$ modules:
$$f^*G=f^{-1}G\otimes_{f^{-1}\mathcal{O}_Y}\mathcal O_X$$
which feels incredibly unwieldy to work with from the raw definitions."  - you should be more specific - what exactly are you looking for?

Comment: @hm2020 like a simplification on affine opens or something along those lines

Comment: If $i:=Spec(A):=V \rightarrow X$ is the inclusion of an open affine in $X$ it follows there is an isomorphism of  sheaves $i^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_X) \cong \mathcal{O}_V$. Hence $H^0(V, i^{-1}(\mathcal{O}_X)) \cong A$.

Comment: To "take the topological pullback" to an open subscheme equals "restriction".